# Increase 1% salary for employee who is making lowest salary in dept 10

Tags: mysql, sql

Increasing 1% salary for employee who is making lowest salary in dept 10

my solution

```
update emp set sal = sal + (sal* 1/100) 
where 
sal = (select min(sal) from emp2 where deptno = 10)
```

--1 row updated

but the correct solution is

```
update emp set sal = sal + (sal* 1/100) 
where 
sal = (select min(sal) from emp2 where deptno = 10)
and deptno=10
```

--1 row updated

Here  the question is why mysolution is wrong

1) find out whose is making the lowest sal in deptno 10
select min(sal) from emp2 where deptno = 10--

2)increase 1% salary for employee who is making lowest salary in dept 10 
so,
update emp set sal = sal + (sal* 1/100) 
where 
sal = (select min(sal) from emp2 where deptno = 10)

Comment: It's nice that you can increase salaries by a simple SQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without that `deptno=10` condition in your main query, you'll update all employees who only match a salary amount. That's why the correct answer has that condition for both the sub query and your main query.